# Custom Permalink with child categories creating 404

Tags: categories, permalinks, 404-error

I am trying to have a permalink strucutre as follows:

```
/category [List all the posts for the category]
/category/child-category [List all the posts for the child category]
/category/post-slug
```

My permalink settings is as follows:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

The category base is blank.

But if I navigate to /category/child-category from the URL bar, the link 404s. It only works when I navigate to /child-category without the parent category from the URL bar.

What would I need to do to have the permalink structure that I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean 'I go'? Do you type the URL in the address bar or you follow some navigation links? _Please edit your question_. Also, `/category/child-category/post-slug/` is how it should work with your permalink structure.

Comment: @MaxYudin I have clarified the question and removed the part about 'post' slug as I found out I could simply what I wanted by changing the Primary Category when selecting a category.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why this was not working. I had to set the category base to a dot(.) without any plugins but since I had 'Yoast SEO' Plugin instead, I had the not set the correct settings. To achieve the permalink structure I required:

Without Plugin:

1. Go to Setting > Permalinks
2. Select Custom Structure
3. Add /%category%/%postname%/ after your domain
4. Change Category Base to period/dot.

With Yoast SEO plugin:

1. Go to Yoast SEO
2. Select advanced
3. Click on the tab permalinks at the top
4. Check Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL.

[Here](https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/) is where is got those steps from (and some other ways to remove category base)